# How to implement Video filter on android like instagram

Tags: android, video

I need to add video filter in my android app like **Instagram**. I searched alot but did not find much stuff. Is there any library for this like aviary sdk for image editing ?

Comment: Can you guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: @DJtiwari Which solution didi u refer for video filteration? Any doc to refer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest way to do this would be using OpenCV library for Java (importing it to Android project could be trcky) - it enables you to easaly extract each frame to different types of Image objects on which you can apply your filter (not sure if OpenCV contains tools for doing this) and then composing a new Video with modified frames.

Have in mind that this might be highly both CPU and battery consuming and I am not quite sure how would this work on various hardware configurations.

The other - longer - solution is to dig in to Android NDK and try to use ffmpeg. All in all it might decrease CPU load.

Also the new Android L release will provide some basic filters for Camera (not sure if this includes videos) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xtp3tH27OFs so you could wait for some Compat library

Comment: This library actually embeds and uses ffmpeg to do some really cool stuff (image overlays, face detection, and any raw c++ opengl hackery you like): https://github.com/wysaid/android-gpuimage-plus

Comment: I attempted to use FFMPEG in a previous project, but found it was far too slow for processing. I've written an alternative to FFMPEG for video (and image) processing, which can be found here: https://github.com/isaac-udy/Kfilter

Answer (score 2):

I have give some filter for video like instagram filter using OpenGL ES. That is very fast and very nice.

If you just want to filter and show the video, u can see about this example, u can visit https://www.virag.si/2014/03/playing-video-with-opengl-on-android/. For another filter u can edit the fragment_shader.

But, if you need to render the video filtered and save that to sd card, you need mediacodec and mediamuxer. You can show the example from here http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/.

Hope this can help u, and sorry about my english.

Comment: Virag link is not functional anymore, please update it.

Comment: [updated link](https://www.virag.si/2014/03/rendering-video-with-opengl-on-android/)

Comment: Updated link is not functional (once again? too? who knows). Updated link: [https://www.virag.si/2014/03/playing-video-with-effects-using-opengl-on-android/](https://www.virag.si/2014/03/playing-video-with-effects-using-opengl-on-android/)

Comment: @hans can you help me, how can apply filters on video while recording, it will highly be appreciated.