# Add Filters to Video like Instagram or Snapchat via FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am using `FFmpeg` in my android app. I have implemented following filters/effects successfully on video-

1. Invert Color
2. Black and white
3. Sepia
4. Vignette
5. Gamma effect

I followed FFmpeg Video Filter docs.

There are similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25542371/5996106) asked but without any proper answer.

I want to apply some Good Filters like on **Instagram** or **Snapchat** via `FFmpeg` . Below are few [example](https://designpieces.com/2014/09/instagram-filters-css3-effects/) filters taken from [this](https://designpieces.com/2014/09/instagram-filters-css3-effects/) link.

Can these filters be achieved via `ffmpeg` ?

[image: Toaster Filter]

[image: Amaro Filter]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that might be helpful it shows how to use ffmpeg on android, the only thing you need is to find or learn the commands for different actions(filtering, trimming, rotating, etc), and yes you can achieve this with ffmpeg
https://androidlearnersite.wordpress.com/2017/03/17/ffmpeg-video-editor/
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide

Comment: ffmpeg has the possibilities to manipulate with the colors and the link was supposed to help him get started with the commands needed as explained in the answer